# How to split element to two continuable parts and add another element between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's possible to split html element to two continuable parts by specific height and add another element between them automatically using javascript, like spliting image to two parts and add other image between them.

Example :

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
}

.original-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.div1 p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.div2 {
  border-top: none;
}

.div2 p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.new-elem {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<strong>Original</strong>
<hr/>
<div class="original-div">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<strong>Output</strong>
<hr/>
<div class="original-div div1">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
  </p>
</div>
<div class="new-elem">
  INSERTED ELEMENT
</div>
<div class="original-div div2">
  <p>
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a draft that should get you started. Be sure to check all of the invariants in your solution (move the green slider around):

```js
function splitInsert(element, percentage, sibling) {
  let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  let clone = element.cloneNode(true);
  let parent = element.parentNode;
  let inserted = parent.insertBefore(clone, element);
  
  let a_len = element.textContent.length * percentage;
  
  //should check invariants here
  //backup until word boundary
  let i = a_len - 1;
  while (i > 1 && !/\s/.test( inserted.textContent.charAt(i) )) {
    i--;
  }
  inserted.textContent = inserted.textContent.substring(0, i);
  element.textContent = element.textContent.substring(i);
  
  element.style.height  = rect.height * (1 - percentage) + 'px';
  inserted.style.height = rect.height * percentage + 'px';
  parent.insertBefore(sibling, element);
}

let p = document.querySelector('p');
let org_tc = p.textContent;
let org = p.cloneNode(true);
let new_p = document.createElement('p');
new_p.textContent = 'hello, world';
new_p.className = 'new-elem';

splitInsert(p, 0.05, new_p);

function reset() {
  let target = document.querySelector('.original-div');
  while (target.firstChild)
    target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
  org.textContent = org_tc;
  target.innerHTML = `
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
  `;
}
let slider = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
slider.onchange = function (event) {
  reset();
  let p = document.querySelector('p');
  splitInsert(p, event.target.value / 100, new_p);
};
```

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
}

.original-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.div1 p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.div2 {
  border-top: none;
}

.div2 p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.new-elem {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: green">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1">
</div>
<strong>Original</strong>
<hr/>
<div class="original-div">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<strong>Output</strong>
<hr/>
<div class="original-div div1">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
  </p>
</div>
<div class="new-elem">
  INSERTED ELEMENT
</div>
<div class="original-div div2">
  <p>
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

1. allocate heights
2. allocate text content

   1. determine text allocation rules (punctuation, non-breaking spaces, etc.)
3. split & insert